# HCF and prime factorization

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

I'm following along in a math book I'm reading and the task at hand is to find the HCF of $270$ and $900$ using prime factorization. I know the answer is $90$ because I checked the answer at the back of the book and got it wrong.

I know that the only prime factors that go into each of them are $2, 3$ and $5.$ However I'm at a complete loss figuring out where to go from there to get $90.$

Answer (score 0):

$$270 = 2\cdot 5\cdot3^3,\quad 900 = 2^2\cdot 5^2 \cdot 3^2.$$
The HCF is found by taking the smallest exponent of each distinct prime in the products.  So,
$$HCF(270,900) = 2\cdot 5\cdot 3^2 = 90.$$

Comment: When you say exponent do you mean power? If yes, how do you determine which prime the exponent goes to and to what multiple, as in 3 to the power of two or three to the power of 3? I got it right at one stage but it was just from trial and error.

Comment: I'm picking the factor with the smaller power each time. $2^1$ vs. $2^2$, $3^2$ vs $3^3$... Make sense?

Comment: Sorry I'm not really following, let's say I have the list of common primes, in this instance 2, 3 and 5. What method do I need to follow to determine which way to multiply and exponentiate them in order to get the HCF?

Comment: Let's say the number $2$ is common to both prime factorisations.  Look at each number's prime factorisation.  Choose the power of $2$ that is the larger of the two.  This becomes one factor of the HCF.  Proceed to the next distinct prime...

Comment: Give yourself a change to practice:  Find the HCF of 45 and 250.  I will check your answer.

Comment: Ok so the prime factors of 45 and 250 are 3 and 5, by guesswork I figured 3 X 3 X 5 = 45, but it was simply that, guesswork and trial and error. I can't figure out what to do after that with 250 either.

Comment: Oh, I see.  You are saying you have to guess to find prime factorisation?  Here is the method I use: Find smallest prime factor first.  Then, divide by that number as many times as you can.  When you can no longer divide, move onto the next prime number and repeat.

Comment: I actually made a mistake there the prime factorisation of 45 is 3 and 5 whereas 250 is 2 and 5. So here's what I calculated by trial and error... 3 X 3 X 5 is 45 and 2 X 5 X 5 X 5 is 250

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137378/discussion-between-general-raid-and-doug).

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).